Recover USB Drive Partitions
I think i messed up my WB external HDD while copying some files from Windows. My mistake was yanking the port out. I have done it many times before on Ubuntu... without any issues. But this time I think i toasted the drive. So my current situation is:
When i login to Ubuntu and plug in the drive... I can see it in Disks, and when I use the lsusb command. But the partitions do not show. Any idea on how to recover it? It has a lot of important data in it which i would like to get back.
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0c45:670b Microdia Integrated_Webcam_HD
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 0cf3:0036 Qualcomm Atheros Communications AR9462 Bluetooth
Bus 001 Device 010: ID 046d:c31c Logitech, Inc. Keyboard K120
Bus 001 Device 013: ID 1058:2627 Western Digital Technologies, Inc. My Passport 2627

The Device 013 is the one.
And on Disks, I see:

I it supposed to have two partitions in it. A 4TB one and a 1TB one. Dont see both.
Any help would be appreciated.

What does gdisk show? sudo gdisk -l /dev/sdb if still sdb. http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/repairing.html My system sometimes moves drive to first or sda on reboot. Always check drive order. Does testdisk see partitions, also? http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step
